# Visual studio for Mac able to compile the project even if there is an error line

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a tabbed page in Xamarin forms, and when I try to add the code for the tabbedpage placement, it shows that the attachable property for "ToolbarPlacement" was not found in TabbedPage with a red underline, but when I try to compile my code it does not not show any error and I able to run the code, is there any ways to check where the problem occurs? Because all the code is working.

Things that I have tried:

1) reinstall my visual studio Mac

2) update my xamarin.forms

3) rebuild my solution

4) tried the same code in other Mac, and its working

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PLUS.Views" 
            x:Class="PLUS.Views.MainPage"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#00a94f"
            android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#8e8e93"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PLUS;assembly=PLUS"
            Title="MainPage" 
            >
```

Comment: Xamarin's XAML Intellisense has been hit or miss for years in various areas and across versions, report it as a bug : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html

Comment: @SushiHangover Alright, thank you so much, is there any ways to repair the Intellisense?

Comment: No, just have to report it as a bug

Comment: @YongSinChen is Sin Chen your real name ? :)

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta yeh hahahh actually is Chen Yong Sin, why?

Comment: I was confused with your name is "shin chan". both are slightly different.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta hahahhaha is totally different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the Xamarin's XAML Intellisense bug. Just report to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html